# Unmount or remove previously opened component before opening again

Tags: reactjs

I have an inline edit component for the table. Whenever I click on the table cell it opens a small edit window to edit it.

Problem- if I am clicking on another cell it opened a new edit window and it will end up with multiple edit windows on the screen.

Need suggestions to remove/unmount the previous instance of the edit window. removing DOM element throwing an uncaught exception.

```
Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.
```

## Edits ---

Edit Component Code -

```
class TextEdit extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { isInlineEditVisible: false };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <span
                style={{
                    marginLeft: '10px',
                }}
            >
               <CellAction>
                   <EditIconButton
                       size={16}
                       onClick={() => {
                            this.setState({ isInlineEditVisible: true });
                     }}
                   />
               </CellAction>

                {this.state.isInlineEditVisible && (
                        <InlineEdit
                            label={this.props.label}
                            value={this.props.param.dataPoint}
                            onSave={(value) => {
                                this.props.onSave(value, this.props.param);
                            }}
                            onCancel={() => {
                                this.setState({ isInlineEditVisible: false });
                            }}
                        />
                    </span>
                )}
            </span>
        );
    }
}
```

I have written this component as a wrapper of InlineEdit component because I need it with each cell of multi-column table.

Comment: Can you share a piece of code showing the location of this edit window relative to table cell ?

Comment: make your "small edit window" a modal one or add a full window div floating (`position: absolute;`) behind it to stop the user from clicking on the table or track the state of your "small edit window" to check if it is visible if it is then close it and open the new one... you could do it also with `React.useEffect()` or set the state in `componentDidMount()`... Please add some of your code to be able to solve your question...

Comment: @AjayVarghese added code.

Comment: @DIEGOCARRASCAL added the code

Comment: @PrashantSharma So each cell has the edit window in it, right ??

Comment: I would like to close the previously opened edit window before opening the new one. 

I was thinking to use @DIEGOCARRASCAL approach but I have click one extra time because on first click outside edit window I have close and on the next click, I will open a new window.

Comment: Yes @AjayVarghese

Comment: In that case instead of a boolean, store the index or id of the cell, for which you need the edit window to be open. While looping through cells data to render cell Component, you can check whether the cell id/index matches with the one in state and show the editWindow.

Comment: @AjayVarghese, this is what i am trying. Thanks for the prompt response

Comment: @PrashantSharma I have added sample code under answer. Check it out and please mark it as the answer, if that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the idea. Let's call the wrapper where you loop through cells as **CellWrapper** and **Cell** for the cell component.

```
const Cell = ({ cell, editCellId, setEditCellId }) => (
 <div> 
   // Cell code


   <EditIconButton
     size={16}
     onClick={() => {
       setEditCellId({ editCellId: cell.id });
     }}
   />

   // EditWindow Code
   {editCellId && editCellId === cell.id && <EditWindow />}
 </div>
)

class CellWrapper extends Component{
   state = {
      editCellId: null
   }
   render(){
      const { cells } = this.props;
      return(
        <div>{cells.map( cell => 
          <Cell
            cell={cell}
            editCellId={this.state.editCellId}
            setEditCellId={(editCellId) => this.setState({editCellId})}
          />
         )
        }</div>
      ) 
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 

In my case cell component is class-component. I am using this component as below

`<td>
{param.value}                                    
              <Cell
                                        label='name'
                                        param={param}
                                    />
                                </td>`

Comment: @PrashantSharma You can have the Cell component as a class. The important point here is, you have to maintain state for keeping active edit cell id ( meaning id of the cell for which edit window is opened ) in a level where you have access to all other Cells. In the code above it's CellWrapper component where I loop all the cell and I have the control over all cells there.